# How to install lua-zlib with LuaRocks on Windows?

Tags: windows, lua, zlib, luarocks

I've written a program with Lua, in a Linux environment, and it uses the Lua module `ZipWriter` and its dependecies (`lua-zlib` and `struct`). I'm trying to release to Windows as well, but I'm having trouble building [`lua-zlib`](https://luarocks.org/modules/brimworks/lua-zlib).

I'm using LuaRocks to install all other packages, with standard commands. So, to install `lua-zlib`, I just used `> luarocks install lua-zlib`, but of course it wouldn't work, as [`zlib`](https://www.zlib.net/) itself wasn't installed, and `lua-zlib` is a binding to that library.

```
Installing https://luarocks.org/lua-zlib-1.2-0.src.rock

Error: Could not find header file for ZLIB
  No file zlib.h in c:/external/include
  No file zlib.h in c:/mingw/include
  No file zlib.h in c:/windows/system32/include
You may have to install ZLIB in your system and/or pass ZLIB_DIR or ZLIB_INCDIR to the luarocks command.
Example: luarocks install lua-zlib ZLIB_DIR=/usr/local
```

So, I found [a link](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/zlib.htm) in that page for different downloads of `zlib` for Windows. I downloaded both the "Complete package, except sources" and "Sources" Setups, installed them, and they created folders and files under the directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32`, all related to `zlib`. I followed the example provided by that error log and tried running `luarocks` again:

```
> luarocks install lua-zlib ZLIB_DIR="C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32"
```

But again, another error:

```
Installing https://luarocks.org/lua-zlib-1.2-0.src.rock

mingw32-gcc -O2 -c -o lua_zlib.o -IC:\lua\luajit lua_zlib.c -DLZLIB_COMPAT -IC:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32/include
mingw32-gcc -shared -o zlib.dll lua_zlib.o -lC:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32/zlib C:\lua\luajit/lua51.dll -lMSVCRT
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lC:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32/zlib
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Error: Build error: Failed compiling module zlib.dll
```

And indeed, there was no file/directory in `C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32/zlib`, as the error shows. For some reason, that was not installed. What am I missing?

Note: as the error log shows, I have `mingw32-gcc` as the compiler, in case this is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work using a static zlib instead. To do so, you can follow this [guide](https://github.com/brimworks/lua-zlib/issues/42) on Github. Basically, you need

1. Functional zlib library installed
   Download from https://zlib.net , use `cmake` to generate Visual Studio solution (e.g. in c:\lib\zlib)

   ```
   cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=c:\lib\zlib
   ```

   then build the INSTALL project from the resulting solution, using 'Release' build type in VS.
2. Download luarock lua-zlib:

   ```
   mkdir c:\lib\lua-zlib
   c:
   cd \lib\lua-zlib
   luarocks download lua-zlib
   ```
3. Edit your lua-zlib*.rockspec file (e.g. in c:\lib\lua-zlib), 
   add , `"ZLIB_STATIC"` to `build.modules.zlib.defines`, 
   change `platform.windows.modules.zlib.libraries` from `"$(ZLIB_LIBDIR)/zlib"`
   to `"$(ZLIB_LIBDIR)/zlibstatic"`
4. Install the luarock from local source (change the filename to match the existing one):

   ```
   cd c:\lib\lua-zlib 
   luarocks install lua-zlib*.rockspec
   ```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that guide! Actually after building with VS, to make the build work with just `luarocks install lua-zlib`, I just had to copy `C:\lib\zlib\lib\zlib.lib` to `C:\lib\zlib\zlib.lib`, and it worked.

Comment: An important correction, using the static lib was indeed necessary. What I actually did now was copying `C:\lib\zlib\lib\zlibstatic.lib` to `C:\lib\zlib\zlib.lib`. This is way it uses the static lib but you don't have to edit the rockspec